# Get highest value in sublist fast

Tags: algorithm, performance, data-structures

I have a list of numbers. The UI frequently checks the highest value in specific range of this list. For example the highest value between index 10000 and 12000.
The list is not sorted. The order of the values must be preserved. For example index 10000 to 12000 must always have the same values.

What is the fastest way to get the highest value in a sublist?

Of course I could use a simple loop. But that would be O(n) and I have heavy performance issues due to the large amount of data. The UI becomes very slow.

Is there an algorithm or data structure to get the highest value in O(logn) or O(1)? It would be no problem to prepare the data in a complex manner, if access was quick afterwards.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Range_minimum_query

Comment: Did any of the answers help?

Answer (score 1):

You can do all operations in `O(log(n))` with the following structure.

Set up an array of arrays with `O(log(n))` levels with `max_val[i][j]` being the maximum value from indexes `j * 2**i` to `(j + 1) * 2**i - 1`. So `max_val[0]` is your raw data, `max_val[1]` has the maximums of pairs, and so on.

To update the value with the `j`th index, we just set `max_val[0][j]` and then recalculate `max_val[1][j//2]`, of `max_val[2][j//4]` and so on until it does not change. On average `O(1)` layers get updated, and the worst case is `O(n)`.

To find the maximum of the range from `j` to `k`, just have to look at `O(log(n))` levels in a pattern that works from the outside in.

1. Start at both ends with `max_val[0][j]`. Add both to the list.
2. If the ends are the same, stop. Else add both the the list and continue.
3. If the `j` for the bottom end is odd, add 1 to it, and add that to the list.
4. If the `j` for the top end is even, subtract 1 from it, and add that to the list.
5. Go up a level and at both ends go from `max_val[i][j]` to `max_val[i][j//2]`. Then go to step 2.

Here is your 10000 to 12000 example to show you the entries that need to be looked at.

```
max_val[ 0][10000], max_val[ 0][12000] # Start
max_val[ 0][10000], max_val[ 0][11999] # Close in
max_val[ 1][ 5000], max_val[ 1][ 5999] # Up a level
max_val[ 1][ 5000], max_val[ 1][ 5999] # Close in
max_val[ 2][ 2500], max_val[ 2][ 2999] # Up a level
max_val[ 2][ 2500], max_val[ 2][ 2999] # Close in
max_val[ 3][ 1250], max_val[ 3][ 1499] # Up a level
max_val[ 3][ 1250], max_val[ 3][ 1499] # Close in
max_val[ 4][  625], max_val[ 4][  749] # Up a level
max_val[ 4][  626], max_val[ 4][  749] # Close in
max_val[ 5][  313], max_val[ 5][  374] # Up a level
max_val[ 5][  314], max_val[ 5][  373] # Close in
max_val[ 6][  157], max_val[ 6][  186] # Up a level
max_val[ 6][  158], max_val[ 6][  185] # Close in
max_val[ 7][   79], max_val[ 7][   92] # Up a level
max_val[ 7][   80], max_val[ 7][   91] # Close in
max_val[ 8][   40], max_val[ 8][   45] # Up a level
max_val[ 8][   40], max_val[ 8][   45] # Close in
max_val[ 9][   20], max_val[ 9][   22] # Up a level
max_val[ 9][   20], max_val[ 9][   21] # Close in
max_val[10][   10], max_val[10][   10] # Meet!
```

This generates a list of `O(log(n))` entries, the maximum of which is the answer to your query.

Comment: The idea is good but not that in practice using a log2 is not very efficient because it uses a significant amount of memory and it is not much cache efficient. Something like a log16 should be better. The best fit is dependent of the size of the items and the cost to compare them (for big&slow objects log2 is fine, and for very-small&cheap ones, log32 should be quite good). Using fewer levels reduce the number of (expensive) cache misses. One may use a fixed amount of level for both sake of simplicity and practical performance.

Comment: @JérômeRichard Memory is not that bad. Using log2 doubles memory over a straight array. You are right about cache wins for using fewer levels. However the logic becomes more complex.

Answer (score 0):

To get the maximum value in a sublist fast, you can use a [`Segment tree`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Segment_tree).

Below snippet uses Segment Tree to achieve the same. Let's take the below array example.

```
3, 2, 1, 4, 6, 8, 2
```

*One of the* possible valid segment tree would look like:

[image]

For better live demonstration, you can try [`here`](https://visualgo.net/en/segmenttree).

For every range of powers of 2, we have precomputed the  max values. When we wish to compute the range which half covers each precomputed range, we drill down further to get the correct range values w.r.t our segment tree ranges.

The segment tree nodes start from 1 at the top and then moves down each level from left to right in a level - order traversal fashion to store the values.

**Snippet(Python):**

```
import math
def query(segT, L, R, l, r, segIdx):
    if L == l and R == r: return segT[segIdx]
    mid = (L + R) >> 1
    if r <= mid:
      return query(segT, L, mid, l, r, segIdx << 1)
    elif l > mid:
      return query(segT, mid + 1, R, l, r, (segIdx << 1) + 1)
    return max(
            query(segT, L, mid, l, mid, segIdx << 1), 
            query(segT, mid + 1, R, mid + 1, r, (segIdx << 1) + 1)
          )
    
def update(segT, L, R, idx, val, currSegIdx):
  if L == R:
    segT[currSegIdx] = val
    return
  mid = (L + R) >> 1
  if idx <= mid:
    update(segT, L, mid, idx, val, currSegIdx << 1)
  else:
    update(segT, mid + 1, R, idx, val, (currSegIdx << 1) + 1)
  segT[currSegIdx] = max(segT[currSegIdx << 1], segT[(currSegIdx << 1) + 1])

ls = [3, 2, 1, 4, 6, 8, 2]
size = len(ls)
segT = [-math.inf for _ in range(4 * size + 1)]

for i in range(size):
    update(segT, 1, size, i + 1, ls[i], 1)
```

[**Live Demo**](https://onecompiler.com/python/3zps2x93f)

**Time complexity:** `O(log(n))` for each query where `n` is the length of the list. Overall is `O(n log(n))` since we are building the tree.

**Space Complexity:** `O(n)` where `n` is the length of the list.